# Convert LocalDate.toEpochDay to "yyyy-MM-dd" in Oracle SQL function?

Tags: java, oracle, time, java-time

I am storing the result of [`LocalDate.toEpochDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toEpochDay--) (a 64-bit long integer) in a column in an Oracle SQL table. The epoch day is a simple incrementing count of days where day 0 is 1970-01-01.

I need a way for Oracle SQL users to convert that value to a string with a format of `"yyyy-MM-dd"`

What might such an Oracle SQL function look like?

I would also need the inverse function.

Also to-from Oracle `DATE` type would be nice.

I have a feeling that the epochDay to `"yyyy-MM-dd"` function would help me find the other three.

In other words: What is the Oracle SQL equivalent of

```
LocalDate.ofEpochDay(epochDay).toString()
```

?

Reference:

- [LocalDate.ofEpochDay](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofEpochDay-long-)
- [LocalDate.toEpochDay](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toEpochDay--)

Comment: What is the exact data type of the database column?

Comment: @BasilBourque the type of the column is NUMBER(19)

Comment: You should edit your Question for additional information or clarification rather than post as comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
to_char(date'1970-01-01' + epoch_day, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
date'2016-07-26' - date'1970-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive you can try something like this, based on [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1123941?tstart=0) thread which I believe will help you.

```
TO_DATE('19700101000000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')+((DATE_FIELDS-18000) /(60*60*24))
```